# Если в ссылке 2 слова (и более) сокращать первое слово

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Есть `jQuery` скрипт, который фильтрует`div-ы` с классами `cm` и атрибутами `cl` (больше 4). В `div class="cm"` есть ссылки, в которых может быть как и одно слово, так и несколько. Как сократить первое слово до одной буквы и поставить точку (Стол кухонный -> С. кухонный), если в ссылке есть два и более слова.

```js
$("div.cm").each(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).attr('cl') > 4 && jQuery(this).hasClass('cm')) {
    jQuery(this).html("I have it it");
  } else {
    jQuery(this).html("I don't have it");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cm">C классом но без атрибута</div>
<div class="cm" cl="5">С классом и атрибутом 5
  <div class="has_link">
    <a>Стол кухооный</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cm" cl="2">С классом и атрибутом 2</div>
<div></div>
<div class="cm">C классом но без атрибута</div>
<div class="cm" cl="5">С классом и атрибутом 5</div>
<div class="cm" cl="6">С классом и атрибутом 7
  <div class="has_link">
    <a>Стол</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cm" cl="7">С классом и атрибутом 7
  <div class="has_link">
    <a>Стол кухооный раскладной</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен, правильно ли понял вопрос. Но сократить первое слово можно простой регуляркой. Вот код который пробегается только по ссылках:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((element) => {
  if (/\s/.test(element.innerText)) {
    element.innerText = element.innerText.replace(/^(.)(\S+)(.*)$/, '$1. $3');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="has_link">
  <a>Стол кухооный</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="has_link">
  <a>Стол</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="has_link">
  <a>Стол кухооный раскладной</a>
</div>
```

upd:

```js
$("div.cm").each(function(index, div) {
  if (jQuery(this).attr('cl') > 4) {
    const a = $(div).find('a');
    if (/\s/.test(a.text())) {
      a.text(a.text().replace(/^(.)(\S+)(.*)$/, '$1. $3'));
    }
  } else {
    jQuery(this).html("I don't have it");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cm">C классом но без атрибута</div>
<div class="cm" cl="5">С классом и атрибутом 5
  <div class="has_link">
    <a>Стол кухооный</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cm" cl="2">С классом и атрибутом 2</div>
<div></div>
<div class="cm">C классом но без атрибута</div>
<div class="cm" cl="5">С классом и атрибутом 5</div>
<div class="cm" cl="6">С классом и атрибутом 7
  <div class="has_link">
    <a>Стол</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cm" cl="7">С классом и атрибутом 7
  <div class="has_link">
    <a>Стол кухооный раскладной</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но я не могу поместить ваш скрипт внутрь моего. Что бы ваш скрипт работал только если в div есть определенный класс и атрибут.

Comment: Почему не можете?

Comment: Не хватает опыта )) Если вставляю вместо jQuery(this).html("I have it it"); то регулярка работает по всей странице.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.